# How to add click to RecyclerView whole row and a specific row item separately?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with two `TextView`s and one `ImageView`. I want to add separate click to whole each row and the `ImageView`in each row seperately. Is it possible?

Here is my Adapter class:

```
public class ContactsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<ContactsDataModel> dataList;
private Typeface tfSegoeui;
Context context;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, detail;
    public ImageView catIcon, imgCall;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        detail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        catIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.catIcon);
        imgCall = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgCall);
    }
}


public ContactsListAdapter(Context context, List<ContactsDataModel> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ContactsDataModel dataModel = dataList.get(position);
    tfSegoeui = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.title.getContext().getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/segoeui.ttf");
    holder.title.setText(dataModel.getName());
    holder.detail.setText(dataModel.getPersonalNumber());
    holder.imgCall.setTag(dataModel.getPersonalNumber());
    holder.catIcon.setImageResource(dataModel.getImage());
    holder.title.setTypeface(tfSegoeui);
    holder.detail.setTypeface(tfSegoeui);

           holder.imgCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String number = holder.imgCall.getTag().toString();
            Log.d("number", number);
            String num = "tel:" + number;

            try {
                Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(num));
                context.startActivity(dialIntent);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Your call has failed...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
            TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        String LOG_TAG = "Call contact ";
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            //wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so you know your app initiated the call.
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            //when this state occurs, and your flag is set, restart your app
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you want separate click for each row and image separately?

Comment: secondly why are using two setonclicks on imgCall?

Comment: @AliAsheer Yes. I have a call icon in the right side of each row. If user clicks that, I want to start an Intent to make call. If user taps anywhere outside that icon, I want to start another Activity.

Comment: let `MyViewHolder` implement `View.OnClickListener` and setup all of your click listeners inside `MyViewHolder` constructor

Comment: @AliAsheer Ignore that pls

Comment: you can set an onclicklistener on a RelativeLayout or whatever is that you are using. Or you can use cardview and place the items inside cardview

Comment: You should give id to the parent layout you've used in your `contacts_list_row` file and than make a variable of that layout in your `MyViewHolder` class and after that you can make click listener on that variable, It will be same as you made click listener on your `imgCall` variable.

Comment: kindly try my solution it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your single row layout file as

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public TextView title, detail;
public ImageView catIcon, imgCall;
//add item_row layout e.g
public RelativeLayout rel;


public MyViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    detail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
    catIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.catIcon);
    imgCall = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgCall);
    rel= (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(your_id_here);


rel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       //whatever you want here
    }
});
}
}
```

Comment: I want to pass the position of the clicked RecyclerView item to next activity. I cannot do that this way.

Comment: @JasmineThomas yes you can, read `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` documentation

Answer (score 0):

you can add to click listener to any view like this inside `ViewHolder` class

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public TextView title, detail;
public ImageView catIcon, imgCall;

public MyViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    detail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
    catIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.catIcon);
    imgCall = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgCall);
    imgCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
    title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
    catIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
     detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
}
```

}

and if you want position of the item clicked.

add this line inside your `onBindViewHolder`

```
title.setTag(position);
```

get position using `title.getTag()`

Comment: why 4 anonymous `View.OnClickListener`? its a lot easier to implement `View.OnClickListener` in `MyViewHolder`... also, you dont need `getTag` to get the position inside `ViewHolder`

Comment: yeah, implementing View.OnClickListener is the best way.
I thought this would be simpler for him to understand :)

Comment: but that's not the question

Comment: @AliAsheer what is `not the question`?

Comment: @psink the question is to  setOnClick for complete row and an item inside that row separately, check my answer

Comment: @AliAsheer in your answer you are setting the click listener inside `onBindViewHolder` which is wrong, the above answer is almost correct since the listeners should be set inside `ViewHolder`

Comment: It's not wrong, what you are saying is your preference i.e setting it in MyViewHolder. Secondly this answer is still out of context.

Comment: @AliAsheer `onBindViewHolder` is called many, many times, and each time you are creating a `new View.OnClickListener()` which is wrong

Comment: @AliAsheer yes, onBindViewHolder will be called infinitly whenever data is reset to one of ViewHolders

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code for item click event.

**ContactsListAdapter**

```
private List<ContactsDataModel> dataList;
    private Typeface tfSegoeui;
    Context context;

    public interface OnContactClick {
        public void onContactClick(int position);
    }

    OnContactClick onContactClick;

    public void setOnContactClick(OnContactClick onContactClick) {
        this.onContactClick = onContactClick;
    }
```

Add this in **onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ContactsDataModel dataModel = dataList.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(onContactClick != null) {
                    onContactClick.onContactClick(position);
                }
            }
        });
```

Add below line in **activity**

```
ContactsListAdapter contactsListAdapter = new ContactsListAdapter(this, dataList);
        contactsListAdapter.setOnContactClick(new ContactsListAdapter.OnContactClick() {
            @Override
            public void onContactClick(int position) {
                //You will receive event when clicking item in list
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

save

```
View itemView
```

in the holder and do setonclick like you did with the imgCall

also you did two onclick listeners on imgCall